# Jest testMatch config for '+state' files

Tags: angular, jestjs

I am using unit tests with Jest for my Angular project. The setup works fine, unless I want to test files in with a "+" in the path, as e.g. for a file with the path "src/lib/+state/auth.effects.spec.ts".

I run the test with

```
jest src/lib/+state/auth.effects.spec.ts
```

The console output is

```
No tests found, exiting with code 1
Run with `--passWithNoTests` to exit with code 0
In /Users/luki/Applications/givve/lunch-admin-webapp/libs/auth
68 files checked.
testMatch: **/+(*.)+(spec|test).+(ts|js)?(x) - 17 matches
testPathIgnorePatterns: /node_modules/ - 68 matches
testRegex:  - 0 matches
Pattern: src/lib/+state/auth.effects.spec.ts - 0 matches
```

I guess the problem is with the jest config part of

```
testMatch: ['**/+(*.)+(spec|test).+(ts|js)?(x)']
```

Unfortunately prefixing state-files with a "+" is the naming convention in the project.

Any ideas how to include those files?

Comment: I think the problem is not with "+" -  have you tried to rename it for testing purposes?

Comment: your path could not be correct(I am not sure, cause using NX workspace and "+" works). Try to run all tests without path and look if there are those tests.

Comment: If I rename the directory to "state" the test runs as expected. If I run all tests the mentioned spec is run also. The issue appears only when a specific file is targeted with a path in the command, as mentioned in the description.

Answer (score 0):

On further research I stumbled upon the option --runTestsByPath. Specifying the path this way works.

```
jest --runTestsByPath "src/lib/+state/auth.effects.spec.ts"
```

https://jestjs.io/docs/en/cli#--runtestsbypath